# Fixed point iterative method error MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the fixed point iteration method with initial approximation `x(1)=0`  to obtain an approximation to the root of the equation `f(x)=3x+sin(x)e^x=0`.
The stopping criterion is

> |x(k+1)-x(k)|<0.0001

```
x(1) = 0;
n = 100;

for k = 1:n
    f(k) = 3*x(k) +sin(x(k))-exp(x(k));

    if (abs(f(k))<0.0001)
        break;
    end
    syms x
    diff(f(k));
    x(k+1) = x(1)- (f(k))/(diff(f(k)));
end
[x' f']
```

> This is the error I am getting: Error using  / Matrix dimensions must
>   agree. Error in prac2Q2 (line 15)
>       x(k+1) = x(1)- (f(k))/(diff(f(k)));

Comment: Welcome to SO!... You wrote two different terms for the function `f`, one with `sin( ) * exp( )` and one with `sin( ) - exp( )`.

Comment: Thank you! The correct one would be sin() - exp().

Comment: Even if it worked you will found a fixed point of your function not the root ! Check my answer. Actually you solve the equation `3*x +sin(x)-exp(x) = x` but you want to solve `3*x +sin(x)-exp(x) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to calculate the derivative by hand and use that term as denominator or to save the derivative in another variable and use this as the denominator.

**Derivative as Variable**

```
f(k) = ...;
df(k) = diff(f(k));

x(k+1) = x(k) - f(k) / df(k);
```

---

**PS:** I cannot test this, because I do not have access to the Symbolic Toolbox right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the root of `3*x +sin(x)-exp(x)` you want to resolve this equation:

```
3*x + sin(x) - exp(x) = 0
```

The easiest way will be to isolate `x` in one side of the equation:

```
x = (exp(x) - sin(x))/3 % now iterate until x = (exp(x) - sin(x))/3
```

Now I would recommand to use an easier fixed point method: `x(k+1) = (x(k)+f(x(k)))/2`

```
x = 1                      % x0

while 1
    y = (exp(x)-sin(x))/3; % we are looking for the root not for a fixed point !!! y = f(x)
    x = (x+y)/2            % after a few iterations x == y, so x = (x+y)/2 or x = 2x/2
    if abs(x-y) < 1e-10
        break
    end
end
```

And you obtain the correct result:

```
x =  0.36042
```

No need of symbolic math.